# Excel order form, auto fill text not numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, forms, auto-form-fill

i am creating a two page order form in excel.  When the name, phone and email is entered, I would like it to auto fill on page two

Comment: Please provide a sample about Page One and Page Two, based on your description I cannot create the Worksheets and provide the formula.

Comment: Welcome to Super User please [edit] your post and share the method you have tried so far,, possibly you are working with User Form,,, VBA code,,  if so then share the code,,, and be clear and loud that what data you are suppose to Auto fill !!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to have the data from cell A1 of Sheet1, just your this formula :

`=IF(Sheet1!A1="", "", Sheet1!A1)`